# Ubuntu Can't find pthread library

Tags: linux, pthreads, ubuntu-14.04, configure, linkage

I'm trying to install kumofs on ubuntu (Docker) and getting pthread library not found error while configuring. 
I have already installed libpthread-stubs0-dev.
Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

```
root@67272cb35abf:/home/kumofs# ./configure --with-msgpack=/usr/local/lib/libmsgpackc.so 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864 
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes   
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-  unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for __sync_* atomic operations... yes
checking for inner class friend... yes 
checking if tcbdb is enabled...
checking if tcadb is enabled...
checking for main in -lstdc++... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
configure: error: Can't find pthread library
```

Comment: You need to read config.log (the file, not the screen output) and find out which actual command fails and what input files and error messages are.

Comment: PThread developer files come with `libc6-dev`.

Comment: In addition to @alk's comment, a good way to troubleshoot issues like that is to check whether the library has been installed to a non-standard location. Try `pkg-config --cflags pthread`, and if it doesn't find anything, `find /usr -name pthread*`. If the headers and lib files are there, you can always pass them to the `configure` script on the command line: `./configure --your-options CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I/path/to/include/dir" LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -L/path/to/lib/dir"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Ubuntu 14.04 - 64bits : No errors with kumofs : 
$ `git clone https://github.com/etolabo/kumofs`

$ sudo apt-get install g++ ragel libtokyocabinet-dev

---

```
$ tar xvf msgpack_0.5.7.orig.tar.gz
$ cd msgpack-0.5.7/
$ tar xvf msgpack_0.5.7-3.debian.tar.gz
$ patch -p1 < debian/patches/20_fix_bigendian
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/ && make && sudo make install
```

The two msgpack_0.5.7 source packages :  https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libmsgpackc2 >>> http://mirror.one.com/debian/pool/main/m/msgpack/msgpack_0.5.7.orig.tar.gz ... and http://mirror.one.com/debian/pool/main/m/msgpack/msgpack_0.5.7-3.debian.tar.gz

```
$ cd kumofs/ && ./bootstrap && ./configure && make
```

---

---